# Is cached RAM in use or not?

Tags: linux, memory, cache

I have these stats on my server at the moment:

```
# free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64461      64157        303          0         28      61563
-/+ buffers/cache:       2565      61895
Swap:         4999         35       4964
Total:       69461      64192       5268
```

am I running out of RAM and need to add more, as I only have 303Mb free, or am I okay because I have 61Gb cached and cached RAM that actually isn't in use or something?

Comment: Here's a funny explanation about this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: It's not *cached RAM*, it's *cache RAM*.  The RAM is not cached, it's serving as cache.

Comment: You have a fundamental misconception about how RAM usage works. RAM is a "use it or lose it" resource. So your system works as hard as it can to use as much of it as it can because the only alternative is to waste it. Running out of free RAM is a sign that your system is making efficient use of all the RAM you have and is not an indication that anything is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal - Linux is borrowing unused memory for disk caching. If your systems needs the RAM it will be available.

To view how much free ram you have notice this row:
`-/+ buffers/cache:      61895`

Free represents your free RAM in MB.

You are fine.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks very much for clearing that up for me :D

Comment: May I ask why you have so much RAM?

Comment: @mossy: The OP says it's a server.

Comment: @DragonLord Yes, I understand that. But he's also using 3GB of the 64GB.

Comment: @mossy: A 64-gigabyte configuration can arise from populating all eight memory slots (8x8GB) in a typical DDR3-based dual-socket motherboard.  Notice that only 303 MB are truly unused, and the vast majority of the memory is used as cache.  All this memory makes a big difference in I/O intensive workloads--keep in mind this is a server, which probably has a database, and production databases perform *lots* of disk I/O operations.

Comment: That is good speculation, he could have a database. I ask because I'm afraid that he is confused on the output of free -m and upgraded accordingly? I was simply asking the *OP* why. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @DragonLord If it is indeed a DB Server the DBMS would itself manage its cache - as he system managed cache is much less reliable in general. Please keep this in mind while explaining how servers operate to System Administrators.

Comment: Its got 64Gb of RAM because when buying the server it was either 24Gb or 64Gb of RAM for 10 euros more, so I went with the 64Gb option :P, I was just wondering about this because one of the users of the server got the error "File chunck error, unable to allocated memory" but when I got there the error was gone, so I was wondering if the server had actually managed to run out RAM.

Comment: @ChrisSm the memory management of Linux is plenty reliable. It is just that the memory use of a DBMS is different enough that they consider they have to do it on their own.

Comment: Cache RAM is definitely in use. It's holding cached data. And any RAM that's not locked is available if your system needs RAM, whether cache or not.